# Spark - groupByKey map-side aggregation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Read in "Learning Spark" that

> groupByKey() in RDD disables map-side aggregation as the aggregation
>   function (appending to a list) does not save any space.

However from my understanding, instead of groupByKey, using something like reduceByKey or  (CombineByKey + a combiner function,) we could reduce the data shuffled around.

Wondering why map-side aggregation is disabled for groupByKey() and why it wouldn’t save space at the executor where data is received after the shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

groupByKey doesn't know whether map side aggregations would save anything and how to do them as it has no information on the aggregation you are planning to do (if any). 
reduceByKey or combineByKey are provided with an aggregate function which means spark can actually do this optimization.

Comment: Ah! my bad - I was looking at https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html and thought groupByKey would automatically do aggregation

Only realised now that it returns a dataset of (K, Iterable<V>) pairs when  called on a dataset of (K, V) pairs

Thanks!